# Need some help getting bluetooth to work

Tags: bluetooth

For some reason my bluetooth will not work it's not block so what's wrong with it? Is it the kernel?

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b729]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:055c Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b002 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 056a:033e Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell the exact information you want know about Bluetooth. I assume that you are asking about bluetooth visibility to other devices.

Well, It's simple:

- Hit the super button (windows key)
- On the search box, type "bluetooth"
- Launch the first application on the list by hitting ->enter
- Just at the top of the window you will see a radio button labeled "Visibility of
  (your device name)".Switch it on.

You can now scan available devices from whatever device you want to connect with your ubuntu machine.

If your question meant to ask fro something else, please edit it.

**Method two:**

open terminal and type

> rfkill list

Check where there is bluetooth.

You will find something like this

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

If bluetooth says `Hard blocked: yes`, please type this

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Try that...then lets Know what happens

Comment: The problem is  Visibility when I click it to turn on will not turn on at all.  I don't know how to scan to see what the problem is.

Comment: There are no blocks 

 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
angela@angela-W65-67SZ ~

Comment: Could it be the kernel?

Comment: @UsagiTsukino have studied your Kernel...I don't see any problem with it, unless there is someone else who can locate it. Have you tried just typing `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`....If that does not work then try this  `sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/bluetoothd`  then  `sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: Didn't work.  When I click on bluetooth it says Bluetooth is disable